# Thread function timing

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

When you create a thread does it automatically start the thread function that's in the parameter?

I'm using

```
iret1 =  pthread_create(&client[i++].tID, NULL, thread_function, NULL);
printf("Thread Created");   //for testing purposes
```

In my thread function I have a print statement at the very top. ex:

```
void *thread_function(void *arg){
    printf("Entered thread function");
    ...
    }
```

Instead of printing `Entered thread function` it prints `Thread Created` right after

And it doesn't print `Entered thread function` until I start another thread, is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least to add a newline `\n` at the end of every [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) format function, and often to call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html), e.g. add a call to `fflush(NULL);` after each of your two `printf` ...

Don't forget that `<stdio.h>` functions are buffered. See [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html) function and man page.

**The reason why your output is not printed as soon as you want it to be is that it is staying in the buffer of `stdout`.**

And you probably have no guarantee on the output. The individual characters might perhaps be intermixed. Read [unlocked_stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/unlocked_stdio.3.html) and [flockfile(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/flockfile.3.html) for details.

You may want to read (several times) some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)...

PS you could consider using directly the [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) syscall (without using any `<stdio.h>` function).

Comment: Would \n be the reason it's not printing? And looking at the fflush page does this mean that the thread function does start but i'm just not seeing the `Entered ...` print? Which is what i really want to know

Comment: So the thread function is running but it's just that the printf message is in the buffer of stdout? I'm only using printf to test if the thread function starts or not

Comment: I don't understand why you need to test if the thread function starts... it surely does if `pthread_create` did not fail (it returns 0 on success, non zero on failure).